# Trying to use script tag inside Inertia/Vue Component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

Im trying to SSR render Schema data for my blopost in Vue/Inertia component template.

I got the following error:

```
[plugin:vite:vue] Tags with side effect (<script> and <style>) are ignored in client component templates.
```

```js
<title>{{ post.title }} - {{appName}}</title>
<meta name="og:title" :content="`${post.title}`" />
<meta name="og:description" :content="`${post.featured_content}`" />
<meta name="description" :content="`${post.featured_content}`"/>
<meta property="og:image" :content="`${appUrl}/storage/${post.banner}`" />

<script type='application/ld+json' :v-html="post.schema_data"></script>
```

Comment: I've updated my answer to work with json-ld

Answer (score 0):

Script tags aren't allowed in vue templates. Use a package like vueuse and their `useScriptTag` hook.

```js
<script setup>
import {useScriptTag} from "@vueuse/core";

useScriptTag('/link/to/your/js/file.js')
</script>
```

or you could write your own js to insert a script element into the DOM:

```js
const $scriptElem = document.createElement('script');
$scriptElem.src = '/link/to/your-file.js';

// OR for your particular use case
$script.type = 'application/ld+json';
$scriptElem.innerHTML = `
{
  "@context": "https://json-ld.org/contexts/person.jsonld",
  "@id": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/John_Lennon",
  "name": "John Lennon",
  "born": "1940-10-09",
  "spouse": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cynthia_Lennon"
}
`

document.body.append($scriptElem);
```

This approach works on both script setup and class components.

You could use the same approach for your meta tags.

There's actually a package called [`vue-meta`](https://vue-meta.nuxtjs.org), but it only seems to be compatible with class based components, not script setup.

Comment: The question is about json-ld, not regular script

Comment: @EstusFlask oh, I didn't pay attention to the type attribute. I'll update my answer.

Comment: FWIW, `vue-meta@next` supports V3 but is abandoned, and `@unhead/schema-org` is a suitable replacement